# Was Vorian Atreides' father from Greek mythology?

Tags: greek-myth, brian-herbert

Vorian Atreides' father, Agamemnon, claims to be over a millennia old. Although this isn't quite old enough to be the time of the Greeks back on the original Earth; however, he does refer to his family line to be descended from Atreus.

The original Agamemnon of Greek mythology was the son of Atreus. In greek mythology, Agamemnon and his brother [Menelaus](http://Menelaus) were referred to as the Atreides, hence the [House Atreides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_Atreides), home to Paul, Vorian, Leto, and many others in this family line.

***Was Agamemnon really the original king from Greek mythology, or was he merely another descendant in Atreus' family line?***

*It seems seems impossible that Agamemnon could have been converted into a cymek, as it turns out, ancient Greek technology was not known to have the ability to sustain human brains independently of the body.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agamemnon was the name Andrew Skourus took when he and the other titans decided to take over and enslave the known galaxy. All of the titans picked names from ancient mythology as their new identities. He was not the Agamemnon from Greek Mythology. He took on this title thousands of years after the time period of ancient Greece, as at the point him and the other titans take over humanity has spread across the galaxy.

Comment: I will accept this as soon as I can, I have not read all of the prequels by Brian Herbert and was unclear as to whether the issue was addressed in the books!

Comment: @HankoTanks in the prequels its pretty clear that the titans lived thousands of years later. thousands from our current time as well, most likely.

Comment: I have only read the *Battle of Corrin*, although I intend to read the others. Thank you for the prompt answer. I will accept it as soon as I can.

Comment: @HankoTanks you started with book 3!?@! lol

Comment: @I had no idea that there was more than 1 prequel! I intend to read the others as soon as I can! Marked as answer. Thanks alot.